# Simple C++ Calculating days of the week, a bit stuck?

Tags: c++

So this is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

This is my code. I am completely stuck now, what am I missing here that's right in front of my face? I feel I have all functions in place but I dont think it's going to calculate it correctly. I have some errors in here that I can't fix to even attempt to run it.
Thank you for any help;-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class dayType
{
public:
    void setDay(int dayNum);
    // set the day with the dayNum as parameter
    void printd(dayNum);
    // print the dayNum
    int returnDay();
    // return the day of the week
    void dayAfter();
    // return next day
    void dayBefore();
    // return previous day
    void randomDay(int dayNum);
    // function to return a day after a certain number of days


    dayType(int dayNum);
    // Constructor with parameters setting dayNum according to parameters
    dayType();
    //Default constructor

    private:
        int today;
        int yest;
        int tom;
        int dayN;

    };




    void dayType::printd(int dayNum)
    {
        if (dayNum == 1)
            cout << "Monday" << endl;

        if (dayNum == 2)
            cout << "Tuesday" << endl;

        if (dayNum == 3)
            cout << "Wednesday" << endl;

        if (dayNum == 4)
            cout << "Thursday" << endl;

        if (dayNum == 5)
            cout << "Friday" << endl;

        if (dayNum == 6)
            cout << "Saturday" << endl;

        if (dayNum == 7)
            cout << "Sunday" << endl;

    }


    void dayType::setDay(int dayNum)
    {
    today = dayNum;

    };

    int dayType::returnDay()
    {
        return today;

    };

    void dayType::printd(<#int dayNum#>);
    {
    cout << "The current day is: " << today << endl;
    }


    void dayType::dayBefore()
    {
        if(today == 0)
            yest = 6;
        else today--;
    };


    void dayType::dayAfter()
    {
        if(today == 6)
        tom = 0;

    };

    void dayType::randomDay(int dayNum)
    {
        dayN=(today+dayNum);
        today =(dayN%7);

    };

    dayType::dayType()
    {
        today = 0;
    }


    dayType::dayType(int daynum)
    {
    today = daynum;
    }
    // do I need these constructors here doing this?



            int main()

            {
                int dayWeek;

                cout << "Please enter a number for the day of the week: " << endl;
                cout << "1 - Monday" << endl;
                cout << "2 - Tuesday" << endl;
                cout << "3 - Wednesday" << endl;
                cout << "4 - Thursday" << endl;
                cout << "5 - Friday" << endl;
                cout << "6 - Saturday" << endl;
                cout << "7 - Sunday" << endl;

                while (dayWeek<= 7)

                    cin >> dayWeek;

                dayType thisDay;

                cout << "Today is: ";
                thisDay.returnDay();
                thisDay.printd(int dayNum);


                cout << "Yesterday was: ";
                thisDay.dayBefore();
                thisDay.printd(int dayNum);


                cout << "Tomorrow is: ";
                thisDay.dayAfter();
                thisDay.printd(int dayNum);

                cout << "Type a number of days from today and it will be: ";
                thisDay.randomDay(dayNum);

                return 0;
            };
        }
```

Comment: Hi Croset! I saw some errors in your code. But first, what is your problem? Do you have an error? Is the behaviour not what you're expecting?

Comment: Hi Dylan, honestly I feel I have the functions there but I don't think it's going to work as I plan. Not sure I have the printing correct. There are some basic syntax errors I am receiving first of all so I cant run the program to check - really could appreciate any help as to where I've gone wrong! Thanks :)

Comment: Read some more in your book about *returning* a value from a function and how to call functions. (You've also not completed the definition of the parameter of `printd` in XCode.)

Comment: Like molbdnilo said, you didn't return values. In `returnDay`, you set `dayNum`but this variable doesn't exist. Write this function like this: `int dayType::returnDay(){return today;}`.

Comment: Okay, changed that. Still have a long way to go. Will have another look in my book about return values (it's a terrible book, I wish the school wasn't using it, it has terrible reviews too so please excuse my ignorance) if you could offer anymore guidance that would be wonderful.

Comment: First thing is to show us the error messages. Do you expect us to do it for you ?

Comment: `dayType::printd(int)` implies that days are stored as `1..7`, but the rest of your class seems to store them as `0..6`.  `main()`, like `printd(int)`, uses `1..7`.  Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class dayType
{
public:
    void setDay(int dayNum);
    void printd();
    // set the day with the dayNum as parameter
    void printd(int dayNum);
    // print the dayNum
    int returnDay();
    // return the day of the week
    int dayAfter();
    // return next day
    int dayBefore();
    // return previous day
    int randomDay(int dayNum);
    // function to return a day after a certain number of days


    dayType(int dayNum);
    // Constructor with parameters setting dayNum according to parameters
    dayType();
    //Default constructor

    private:
        int today;

};




void dayType::printd(int dayNum)
{
    if (dayNum == 1)
        cout << "Monday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == 2)
        cout << "Tuesday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == 3)
        cout << "Wednesday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == 4)
        cout << "Thursday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == 5)
        cout << "Friday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == 6)
        cout << "Saturday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == 7)
        cout << "Sunday" << endl;

}


void dayType::setDay(int dayNum)
{
    today = dayNum;

}

int dayType::returnDay()
{
   return today;

}

void dayType::printd()
{
cout << "The current day is: " << today << endl;
}


int dayType::dayBefore()
{
    int yest;
    if(today == 0)
        yest = 6;
    else
        yest = today - 1;
    return yest;
};


int dayType::dayAfter()
{
    int tom;

    if(today == 6)
        tom = 0;
    else 
        tom = today + 1;
    return tom;

};

int dayType::randomDay(int dayNum)
{
    int dayN = (today+dayNum);
    return (dayN % 7)

};

dayType::dayType()
{
    today = 0;
}


dayType::dayType(int daynum)
{
    today = daynum;
}
// do I need these constructors here doing this?



int main()

{
    int dayWeek = -1;
    int random = -1;

    cout << "Please enter a number for the day of the week: " << endl;
    cout << "1 - Monday" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Tuesday" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Wednesday" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Thursday" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Friday" << endl;
    cout << "6 - Saturday" << endl;
    cout << "7 - Sunday" << endl;

    while (dayWeek >= 7 || dayWeek < 0)

        cin >> dayWeek;

    dayType thisDay;
    thisDay.today = dayWeek;

    thisDay.printd();


    cout << "Yesterday was: ";
    thisDay.printd(thisDay.dayBefore());


    cout << "Tomorrow is: ";
    thisDay.printd(thisDay.dayAfter());

    cout << "Type a number of days : ";

    while (random < 0)

        cin >> random;

    cout << "Now we are  ";
    thisDay.printd(thisDay.randomDay(random));

    return 0;
}
```

When you call a function like this : `void fonction(int a, int b)`, you can call it like this : `fonction(1, 2);`. You don't have to write the type of the arguments. In your class, declare only the value you need for your functions. In your previous code, you declared `tom`, `yes`and `dayN` but you don't need to keep their values.

I didn't test the code, so if you have errors, write them and I'll edit this post.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am having a couple errors - an out of line declaration here 

`void dayType::printd();
{`

and here
`thisDay.printd();` seems it does not like printD? Says too few functions to call and dayNum isnt specified?

Comment: You just have to declare void `dayType::printd()`.And I forgot to delete the ; after the implementation.

Comment: AHHHHHH GOTCHA. This makes sense now. Thank you kindly :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would suggest using an `enum` instead of `int` to keep track of the day, along with the necessary operators to allow you to cycle through the days.  This would allow you to more easily define and interact with `dayType`, easily fixing the errors you encountered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

class dayType
{
public:
    // Days enum:
    enum Days {
        D_MONDAY = 1,
        D_TUESDAY,
        D_WEDNESDAY,
        D_THURSDAY,
        D_FRIDAY,
        D_SATURDAY,
        D_SUNDAY
    };

    void setDay(int dayNum);
    // set the day with the dayNum as parameter

    void printd(int dayNum);
    // print the dayNum
    void printd();
    // Prints the current day.

    Days returnDay();
    // return the day of the week
    Days dayAfter();
    // return next day
    Days dayBefore();
    // return previous day
    Days randomDay(int dayNum);
    // function to return a day after a certain number of days


    dayType(int dayNum);
    // Constructor with parameters setting dayNum according to parameters
    dayType();
    //Default constructor

private:
    Days today;
};

// Compound assignment addition:
dayType::Days& operator+=(dayType::Days& left, int right)
{
    typedef dayType::Days Days;

    int temp = static_cast<int>(left) + right;

    // In case of adding negative numbers.
    while (temp < dayType::D_MONDAY)
        temp += dayType::D_SUNDAY;

    while (temp > dayType::D_SUNDAY)
        temp -= dayType::D_SUNDAY;

    left = static_cast<Days>(temp);

    return left;
}

// Compound assignment subtraction:
dayType::Days& operator-=(dayType::Days& left, int right)
{
    typedef dayType::Days Days;

    int temp = static_cast<int>(left) - right;

    while (temp < dayType::D_MONDAY)
        temp += dayType::D_SUNDAY;

    // In case of subtracting negative numbers.
    while (temp > dayType::D_SUNDAY)
        temp -= dayType::D_SUNDAY;

    left = static_cast<Days>(temp);

    return left;
}


// Addition.  Uses compound assignment addition internally.
dayType::Days  operator+(dayType::Days left, int right)
{
    return left += right;
}

// Subtraction.  Uses compound assignment subtraction internally.
dayType::Days  operator-(dayType::Days left, int right)
{
    return left -= right;
}


// Prefix increment (++day):
dayType::Days  operator++(dayType::Days& day)
{
    return day += 1;
}

// Postfix increment (day++):
dayType::Days  operator++(dayType::Days& day, int)
{
    typedef dayType::Days Days;

    Days temp = day;
    ++day;
    return temp;
}


// Prefix decrement (--day):
dayType::Days  operator--(dayType::Days& day)
{
    return day -= 1;
}

// Postfix decrement (day--):
dayType::Days  operator--(dayType::Days& day, int)
{
    typedef dayType::Days Days;

    Days temp = day;
    --day;
    return temp;
}


void dayType::printd(int dayNum)
{
    if (dayNum == D_MONDAY)
        cout << "Monday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == D_TUESDAY)
        cout << "Tuesday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == D_WEDNESDAY)
        cout << "Wednesday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == D_THURSDAY)
        cout << "Thursday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == D_FRIDAY)
        cout << "Friday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == D_SATURDAY)
        cout << "Saturday" << endl;

    if (dayNum == D_SUNDAY)
        cout << "Sunday" << endl;
}

void dayType::printd()
{
    cout << "The current day is: ";
    printd(today);
}


void dayType::setDay(int dayNum)
{
    today = static_cast<Days>(dayNum);
};

dayType::Days dayType::returnDay()
{
    return today;
};

dayType::Days dayType::dayBefore()
{
    return today - 1;
};


dayType::Days dayType::dayAfter()
{
    return today + 1;
};

dayType::Days dayType::randomDay(int dayNum)
{
    return today + dayNum;
};

dayType::dayType()
{
    today = D_SUNDAY;
}


dayType::dayType(int daynum)
{
    today = static_cast<Days>(daynum);
}



int main()
{
    int dayWeek = 0;

    cout << "Please enter a number for the day of the week: " << endl;
    cout << "1 - Monday" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Tuesday" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Wednesday" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Thursday" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Friday" << endl;
    cout << "6 - Saturday" << endl;
    cout << "7 - Sunday" << endl;

    while (!((dayWeek > 0) && (dayWeek < 8)))
        cin >> dayWeek;

    dayType thisDay(dayWeek);

    // -----

    cout << "Today is: ";
    thisDay.printd(thisDay.returnDay());

    // -----

    cout << "Yesterday was: ";
    thisDay.printd(thisDay.dayBefore());

    // -----

    cout << "Tomorrow is: ";
    thisDay.printd(thisDay.dayAfter());

    // -----

    cout << "Type a number of days: ";

    int random;
    cin >> random;
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "In " << random << " days, it will be: ";
    thisDay.printd(thisDay.randomDay(random));
};
```

At the moment, this should work for what you want, with the caveat that if you want to use an `int` as a `Days` (such as to initialise `today` in `dayType::dayType(int daynum)`), you have to explicitly cast it into one.  (Conversely, a `Days` can implicitly be used as an `int`, as demonstrated by passing the return value of `dayType::returnDay()` to `dayType::printd()`, or if you pass a `Days` to `cout`.)

If you want to use `Days` outside of `dayType`, you can use it as `dayType::Days` (such as in the operators' return types).  You can also use `typedef dayType::Days Days;` to bring it into the current scope, allowing you to use it as simply `Days` (such as in `dayType::Days operator++(dayType::Days& day, int)` or `dayType::Days operator--(dayType::Days& day, int)`).  Similarly, to use the enumeration values themselves, prefix their name with `dayType::`.

As you're using this exercise, and your question here, as a learning opportunity, I left a few places where things could be improved.  It currently works properly, but has room for modifications that would make it work better.

Comment: @Croset You're welcome.  I just made a slight fix to `dayType::printd()` (the one without parameters) so it would print the day's name instead of the underlying `int` value, and fixed an error I made in the first paragraph below the code (I had incorrectly stated that you explicitly need to cast a `Days` to `int` to pass it to `std::cout`, when you can actually pass it without casting).